# Problem connecting Firebird in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit

Tags: 12.04

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit on a PC I built recently, I installed Firebird 2.5-Classic, then FlameRobin (open-source database administration tool for Firebird), These packages appeared to install correctly, but when I opened FlameRobin, registered an existing database and attempted to connect, I got the following error message:

```
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Database::Connect
Message: isc_attach_database failed

SQL Message : -902
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements

Engine Code    : 335544344
Engine Message :
I/O error during "open" operation for file "/home/servidorcanario/erp/DB/Arevalo.fdb"
Error while trying to open file
Permission denied
```

I can connect with isql-fb, and I configured Firebird with `dpkg-reconfigure` (PASSWORD & USER), but I really do not understand why I got the error, if the database is indeed there and is not corrupt, and I have already checked it by connecting it to another PC that I have that is running Windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question to show us the output of `ls -l /home/servidorcanario/erp/DB/Arevalo.fdb`.